# Showing bullet chart scales for jQuery sparklines

Tags: jquery, charts, sparklines

I'm using the excellent [jQuery Sparklines](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/#s-about) for drawing small bullet charts in my web app. It's a bit against the nature of tiny graphs like this, but I'd like to render the scales of the bullet trend for example below or above the graph like with the [D3 implementation](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/ex/bullet.html) but in smaller print to accomodate the small size.

I tried to go around the documentation and google about it, but can't find anything about it. Is it even possible or is it just tooltips that I would need to settle with?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no facility for that built into the plugin nor any plans to add it at the current time.

You're free to fork the project on github and add it yourself, of course ;-)

Comment: Fair enough. Went with another solution (not bullet graph) after all.